# Elasticsearch: finding the index of the word for which response document is returned

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-java-api

I am querying elasticsearch and getting an array in return. But the returned array contains multiple sentences. i want to find the index of the word for which the document is returned.
The relevant part of the returned document:

"_id": "AVIcfnn-laLYKmOp14og",
        "_score": 0.17643881,
        "_routing": "1658591699",
        "_parent": "1658591699",
        "_source": {
          "heading": "",
          "paragraphs": [
            "Plug And Stitch With New Compact And Portable Electric Sewing Machine It Is Suitable For Many Functions, Like You Can Do Straight Stitch, 4 Step Button Hole, Free Arm For Circular Stitch, Auto Trip Bobbin Winder, Single Touch Reverse Stitch, Good For Quilting,Lace Work,picot,smoking,cording,blind Hem Stitch,zig-zag Stitch, Etc. Smart Look With Low Maintainence And With Inbuilt Electric Motor Of 60 Watts Warranty Period Two Years , And Service Provided By Company At Your Door Step.",
            "The images represent actual product though color of the image and product may slightly differ.",
            "Apr 13, 2015"
          ]
        },

How to find the word in this data for which this document is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Highlighting`.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html

```
{
    "query" : {...},
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "content" : { fragment_size : 150, number_of_fragments: 1}
        }
    }
}
```

Above snippet will return 1 fragment of size 150 characters for the match. 
Play with `fragment_size` and `number_of_fragments` for maximum effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Elasticsearch Highligher, it will highlight matched string in the give content.

```
{
"query" : {...},
"highlight" : {
    "pre_tags" : ["<tag1>"],
    "post_tags" : ["</tag1>"],
    "fields" : {
        "_all" : {}
    }
 }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html